# Upload image from one server to another server using curl php codeigniter

Tags: php, curl, codeigniter-3

I have one server there is one image, link to a post. I move post content to another server and insert into a new server. but the image does not go. can anyone please tell me, how can I upload an image with post data from one server to another server using curl?

I tried many examples but I did not get success.

Comment: Please post some code, tell us what guidelines you followed, provide further explanation, have pity ^^

Comment: $file_name_with_full_path = realpath("imgs/myimage.jpg");
$postimg = array('myfile'=>'@'.$file_name_with_full_path); 

$headers = array("Content-Type:multipart/form-data");
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postdata);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.secondserver.com/image.php");    
$data = curl_exec($ch);        
curl_close($ch);
I am using this code.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can send the image data in post method from one server and get that post data in the another server.

- you have to mention the server in **action**
- In that another server you have to get the post data and perform the action.